# Error while trying to create module page on MediaWiki

Tags: php, mediawiki, lua

I tried to create a Module page on my MediaWiki but I've been getting the following error:

```
Lua error: Cannot create process: proc_open(/dev/null): failed to open stream: Operation not permitted
```

I'm using a shared hosting plan and manage it through DirectAdmin.

Any help is appreciated!